# ChartJS - Pie/Doughnut Chart Top Cutoff

Tags: chart.js

I'm using the latest chartJS and attempting to create a pie or doughnut chart. This seems like it should be relatively simple to me, but whenever the chart is created the top is cutoff like the image below. I've tried many things to fix this, and searched around with no luck. Has anyone run into this before? Is ChartJS no longer supported in most browsers?

I've seen other pie charts in JSfiddle that people have working, copying the exact same code into new files results in the same chopped off top graphs.

Other graphs work such as line/bar.

Edit: made some progress by changing the chart to load using windows.load. It will now display correctly when the page is resized at all, but will display the same way below initially.

[image: Broken Chart.js image]

Here is the HTML and JS code.

```
            <div class="container-graph-window">
                <canvas id="pieChart" width="435" height="435"></canvas>
                <script>
                    pieChart();
                </script>
            </div> <!-- End continer-graph-window-->
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////JS CODE

```
function pieChart() {

    var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: 300,
                color:"#F7464A",
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                label: "Red"
            },
            {
                value: 50,
                color: "#46BFBD",
                highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                label: "Green"
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#FDB45C",
                highlight: "#FFC870",
                label: "Yellow"
            },
            {
                value: 40,
                color: "#949FB1",
                highlight: "#A8B3C5",
                label: "Grey"
            },
            {
                value: 120,
                color: "#4D5360",
                highlight: "#616774",
                label: "Dark Grey"
            }

        ];

            var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
            window.pieChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive : true});
} //end pie chart
```

Note: I must pass data into the JS function and use it to create the graph.

SOLVED: Update all of your Chart.js files if you run into this issue to the latest version.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle of your HTML, script and the specific Chart2.0 version that you are using? Also, which browser are you using? Cheers!

Comment: I have posted it, thanks.